# How to generate code based on annotations?

Tags: annotations

While i am studying about user defined annotations, i read about writing info about object in a file. 
They said the writing into the file is take cared automatically.

I dont understand that part. How to make this operation to be done automatically without our intervention?

Thanks

Comment: Which language are we talking about here?